# How to tie a keyword (to be pasted) to a key in Linux

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

I have to configure the keyboard to paste text 'abc123' into any program after pressing key combination Alt or Ctrl + a number. It has to work for every program, and I prefer to do it through the command line to have a list that can be run when new combinations are available. So, what is the command for: make Alt + 1 => paste 'abc123' on the cursor.

Comment: Should it be pasted from the clipboard, or similar to typing?

Comment: A multiple pasting tool (CLI configurated) would be ok.